# Printing two 2D arrays side by side

Tags: c, console, printf, multidimensional-array

I've just started doing a unit of programming in C and my first assignment is to make a simple console version of the classic Battleship game.

A part of this - and the part I'm having trouble with at the moment - is displaying information to the player at each turn.

This is what we've been asked to have our display look like:

[image: This is what we've been asked to have our display look like]

And, with a minimum of fuss, I've got mine looking like this:

[image: And, with a minimum of fuss, I've got mine looking like this]

(My `Player` grid is empty at the moment because its 2D array is empty, but if I use an array with something in it, it's fine.)

My header file:

```
/* Header files. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define UNKNOWN ' '

#define SIZE 10

/* Function prototypes. */
void init(char playerHidden[SIZE][SIZE], char playerReveal[SIZE][SIZE],
      char computHidden[SIZE][SIZE], char computReveal[SIZE][SIZE]);
void displayKnownInfo(char playerReveal[SIZE][SIZE],
                  char playerHidden[SIZE][SIZE],
                  char computReveal[SIZE][SIZE]);
```

My C source file:

```
#include "bship.h"

int main(void)
{
   /* Stores player ship position information secret to opponent. */
   char playerHidden[SIZE][SIZE];
   /* Stores player ship position information known to opponent. */
   char playerReveal[SIZE][SIZE];
   /* Stores computer ship position information secret to opponent. */
   char computHidden[SIZE][SIZE];
   /* Stores computer ship position information known to opponent. */
   char computReveal[SIZE][SIZE];

   init(playerHidden, playerReveal,
        computHidden, computReveal);


   displayKnownInfo(playerReveal, playerHidden, computReveal);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


/****************************************************************************
* Function init() initialises every cell in the four grids to a safe default
* value. The UNKNOWN constant is used for the initialisation value.
****************************************************************************/
void init(char playerHidden[SIZE][SIZE], char playerReveal[SIZE][SIZE],
          char computHidden[SIZE][SIZE], char computReveal[SIZE][SIZE])
{
   /*Variables i and j for each dimension of the Arrays*/
   int x,y;

   /*For each increment BETWEEN 0 and 'SIZE', firstly for i;*/
   for(y=0; y<SIZE; y++)
   {
      /*And then for j;*/
      for(x=0; x<SIZE; x++)
      {
         /*Populate that cell with the constant UNKNOWN*/
         playerHidden[x][y]=UNKNOWN;

         playerReveal[x][y]=UNKNOWN;

         computHidden[x][y]=UNKNOWN;

         computReveal[x][y]=UNKNOWN;

      }

   }

}




/****************************************************************************
* Function displayKnownInfo() presents revealed information about the game in
* the format below. In this example, both contestants have made five
* guesses.
* As you can see, the computer player got lucky with all five guesses and has
* sunk the human players' aircraft carrier. The identity of the ship was
* revealed when the aircraft carrier was HIT the fifth time.
* The human player has been less lucky. The first four guesses were a MISS.
* However, the fifth guess was a HIT on the computer players' submarine. The
* human player does not yet know the identity of this ship yet as it is still
* afloat.
* All other squares are still UNKNOWN.
*
*          Player         |         Computer
*    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0  |    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
*   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* a |A| | | | | | | | | | | a | | | | | | | | | | |
*   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* b |A| | | | | | | | | | | b | | | | | | | | | | |
*   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* c |A| | | | | | | | | | | c | | | | | | |=| | | |
*   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* d |A| | | | | | | | | | | d | | |x| | | | | | | |
*   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* e |A| | | | | | | | | | | e | | | | | | | | | | |
*   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* f | | | | | | | | | | | | f | | | | |=| | | | | |
*   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* g | | | | | | | | | | | | g | | | | | | | | | | |
*   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* h | | | | | | | | | | | | h | |=| | | | |=| | | |
*   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* i | | | | | | | | | | | | i | | | | | | | | | | |
*   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* j | | | | | | | | | | | | j | | | | | | | | | | |
*   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
* Aircraft Carrier  (5/5) | 0/5 ships sunk.
* Battleship        (0/4) | 1 hits.
* Destroyer         (0/3) | 4 misses.
* Frigate           (0/3) |
* Submarine         (0/2) |
****************************************************************************/
void displayKnownInfo(char playerReveal[SIZE][SIZE],
                      char playerHidden[SIZE][SIZE],
                      char computReveal[SIZE][SIZE])
{
   /*Ints for stepping through the arrays*/
   int i,j;

   /*First row identifier*/
   char row='a';

   /*Printing first few lines.*/
   printf("          Player         |         Computer\n");
   printf("    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0  |    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0\n");
   printf("   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+\n");
   printf(" %c |", row);

   /*Loop through the arrays*/
   for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
   {
      for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
      {
         /*Print the char at [i][j] with a '|' afterwards.*/
         printf("%c|",playerReveal[i][j]);
      }

      /*After reaching column '0' on the display, increment the row identifier*/
      row++;

      /*And print the 'spacer' row.*/
      printf("\n   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ |   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+");

      /*If the current row identifier is less than 'k', we want to print it*/
      if(row<'k')
      {
         printf("\n %c |",row);
      }
      else
      {
         printf("\n");
      }

      /*And continue until the array has been printed in full.*/
   }

}

}
```

Eventually, the `PlayerHidden` array will be overlaid on the `PlayerReveal` array when a player's ship has been sunk and its identity 'revealed', but for now I'm just wanting to get the computer half of the display working.

Comment: Please do a: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Rizier123 All done, I think.

Comment: Me too :D, hope my answer helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your code after the second loop where you prints stuff:

```
printf("   %c |", row);

for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
{
   /*Print the char at [i][j] with a '|' afterwards.*/
   printf("%c|",computReveal[i][j]);
}
```

So your code looks like:

```
//...
/*Loop through the arrays*/
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
   for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
   {
      /*Print the char at [i][j] with a '|' afterwards.*/
      printf("%c|",playerReveal[i][j]);
   }
   printf("   %c |", row);
   for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
   {
      /*Print the char at [i][j] with a '|' afterwards.*/
      printf("%c|",computReveal[i][j]);
   }
   //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're only printing out the player portion.  Take a look at the code:

```
   for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
   {
      for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
      {
         /*Print the char at [i][j] with a '|' afterwards.*/
         printf("%c|",playerReveal[i][j]);
      }

      // ...
    }
```

You need to have another loop where you print out the computerReveal array

```
   for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
   {
      for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
      {
         /*Print the char at [i][j] with a '|' afterwards.*/
         printf("%c|",playerReveal[i][j]);
      }

      for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
      {
         /*Print the char at [i][j] with a '|' afterwards.*/
         printf("%c|",computReveal[i][j]);
      }

      // ...
    }
```

That should do it.  You're printing out the full width row separators, but not the portion of the array that creates the cell separators